# M-language create SQL queries based on conditions - nested ifs, no idea how to execute

Tags: powerbi

I need to figure out how to run the logic in the `else` bracket of my code, so that the `Source` table is extended depending on the condition of `Sheet1.ItemID`. In the `else`, it should run another DB request to decide whether the DB needs an update or not.
I have the `Security -> Require user approval for new native database queries` enabled and never get a notification that it is going to run the `SELECT` statement. I believe this code has to be done differently.

```
let
    Source = FilterExistingBarcodes,
    #"PSQLQuery" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "SQLQuery", each if [Sheet1.ItemID1] = null
    then 
    "INSERT INTO ""Schema"".""MyTable"" (
        ""Col1"", ) 
    VALUES (
        '" & Text.From([Col1]) & "');" 
    else 
        let
            PostgreSQLSource = PostgreSQL.Database("postgres.database.com", "DBName"),
            response = Value.NativeQuery(PostgreSQLSource, "SELECT id FROM ""Schema"".""MyTable"" WHERE 
            ""Col1"" = '" & Text.From([Col1]) & "');"),
            SubQuery = if response = null
            then
                "UPDATE ""Schema"".""MyTable""
                SET 
                    ""Col1"" = 'UpdateValue' 
                WHERE 
                    ""Col1"" = '" & Text.From([Col1]) & "');"),
            else
                ""
        in 
            SubQuery)
in
    PSQLQuery
```

Edit

Per @Hamza Assada's comment I use `Table.Buffer(Value.NativeQuery(` for the call. It indeed executes the call, I get the prompt to allow running the `SELECT` query.
However, now I get
`Formula.Firewall: Query 'CreateSQLQueries' (step 'PSQLQuery') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.`
I googled and sources say to split the logic up into multiple steps? Is there a better solution than creating all possible combinations?

Comment: the Value.NativeQuery() function does not actually execute the query - it just returns the results as a table. You need to wrap the function in a Table.Buffer() function to force it to execute the query and cache the results.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please be more specific? Like `Table.Buffer(Value.NativeQuery(...))` ?

Comment: The Formula Firewall error you are seeing is a result of Power Query's privacy settings, which are designed to prevent potentially sensitive data from being exposed through queries that combine data from different sources. If your query references other queries or steps that access different data sources, the privacy settings may prevent it from directly accessing a data source.

Comment: To resolve this issue, you can try splitting the logic in your query into multiple steps, so that each step only references data from a single source. Alternatively, you can adjust the privacy settings to allow your query to access the data source directly, by selecting the "Ignore Privacy Levels" option for the data source in the Power Query options.

Another option is to refactor the query so that it only accesses a single data source in each step.

Comment: you could split it into two queries, one to insert new values into the database when Sheet1.ItemID1 is null and another to do an update when it's not null. Then, merge the results of both queries into a single table using the Append Queries feature in Power Query.

Comment: Thank you! This stuff is terrible compared to "real" programming languages, but that I am stuck with it I will have to figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253563/discussion-between-el-dude-and-hamza-assada).